# Creating A Folder From Any Number Of Selected Items In Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Is there a quick way to select several items and place them into a new folder?

Comment: The quick way is to assign a keyboard shortcut to finder's **New Folder from Selection** function. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/keyboard-shortcuts-for-compress-or-new-folder-with-selection

Comment: @bmike Apparently you can also use Cntrl+Cmd+N.

Comment: Now that is even more rapid. I love that I still know so little of all the nooks and crannies of Finder/OS X. I've added that as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finder's File menu has the fastest method to take selected files and make a new nolder with that selection.

1. Select the files
2. Press Control + Command + N
3. Type the name of the folder

[image]

If you require more sophisticated processing, you could script it as described here: [Keyboard Shortcuts for "Compress" or "New Folder with Selection"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/keyboard-shortcuts-for-compress-or-new-folder-with-selection)

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to achieve this:

1. Select the files, compress them into a zip, and then uncompress them into a folder that will be named whatever you named the zip in the first place.

   [image]
2. Select the items you want in the Finder, right-click (or two-finger tap) on them to bring up OS X's contextual menu, and choose the first option: **New Folder with Selection** (shown in the gif below). The Finder will then create a new folder with those items stored safely inside, removing at least one step from the process for you automatically.

   [image]

Comment: @grgarside Totally awesome !!!